# React.js - detect element from which function was called without ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say we have an input field:

`<input type="text" ref="inputBrand" onChange={this.updateState} />`

When the `updateState` function is called, is there a way to know which element it was called from without referencing the `ref`?

```
updateState: function() {
  console.log(inputValue???);
},
```

The reason why I would like to do this without referencing the ref is in the instance that I will have multiple input fields.

If the above is not possible - is it possible to pass the `ref` directly in the function call?

Something like this:

`<input type="text" ref="inputBrand" onChange={this.updateState(--this ref--)} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the input name & input value from the `SyntheticEvent` param which is passed to all event handlers in React.

```
updateState: function(e){
      this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value}, () => console.log(this.state))
},
render: function() {
    return <div>
        <input type="text"  name="a" onChange={this.updateState} />
        <input type="text" name="b" onChange={this.updateState} />
     </div>;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49356/)

Answer (score 2):

```
updateState: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
},
```

Event argument `e.target` will point to DOM element  if you trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the event hander and assign an `id` to each component instead of ref and access it via: `e.target.id` from the function

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  updateState: function(e){
      console.log(e.target.id);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>
        <input type="text"  id="first_input" onChange={this.updateState} />
        <input type="text" id="second_input" onChange={this.updateState} />
     </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49357/)**